# have directory assume name of file

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of video files that I want to put into directories that have the same name as the video file minus the extension (.mov)

For example, given the following directory, how would I write a script to create a directory for each .mov file with the same name as the file (minus the .mov) and then place the .mov file into that directory?

`/Volumes/06a_SD_Video_01/_COLLECTIONS/TR2014_295_Walter_Reed/DER_01/
├── TR2014_295_10_1a_PM.mov
├── TR2014_295_11_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_12_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_13_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_14_1a_PM.mov
├── TR2014_295_15_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_16_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_17_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_18_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_19_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_19_1b_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_1_1a_PM.mov
├── TR2014_295_20_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_21_1a_PM.mov
├── TR2014_295_22_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_22_1b_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_23_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_2_1a_PM.mov
├── TR2014_295_3_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_4_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_5_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_6_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_7_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_8_1a_DER_01.mov
├── TR2014_295_9_1a_DER_01.mov`

Comment: And why would you spam your readers with all those commented-out lines?

Comment: fixed. i thought they might be useful. @Jens

Comment: Apart from the obvious `MEDIAID=$TARGET` or what?

Comment: @tripleee doing that does create a folder with the file name but it also creates a tree directory of every the full path i.e. 
`└── 06a_SD_Video_01
    └── _COLLECTIONS
        └── TR2014_295_XXX
            └── AIPS
                └── Box_02
                    └── TR2014_xxx_xx_xx_PM.mov
                        └── objects
                            └── TR2014_xx_xx_xx_PM.mov`

Comment: I just want `└── TR2014_xxx_xx_xx_PM.mov └── objects └── TR2014_xx_xx_xx_PM.mov`

Comment: creating the directory without the .mov would be great, too.

Comment: your friend's script looks like vogon poetry. better to just clearly describe what you're trying to do and not show us this.

Comment: Ok. I hope that is more clear. @webb

Comment: yes, much! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way:

script:

```
cd "$1"
for m in *.mov; do
  d=`echo "$m" | sed 's/\.mov$//'`
  mkdir "$d"
  mv "$m" "$d"
done
```

usage:

```
sh <scriptname.sh> "<directory>"
```

e.g.,

```
sh mov2dir.sh "/Volumes/06a_SD_Video_01/_COLLECTIONS/TR2014_295_Walter_Reed/DER_01/"
```